# Optimal method to replace string of IDs with different names using map in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I have a set up of 10 "tags" and each has an ID (format: 00:00:00:xx:xx:xx) and translatedID (format: TXT). I get strings listing violating tags which I want to convert from translatedID to ID.

I have a map of the values defined:

```
Map(10) {
  '00:00:00:02:28:47' => 'T7T',
  '00:00:00:02:89:70' => 'T3T',
  '00:00:00:02:89:51' => 'T4T',
  '00:00:00:02:27:bd' => 'T5T',
  '00:00:00:02:89:31' => 'T6T',
  '00:00:00:02:89:a0' => 'T1T',
  '00:00:00:02:89:af' => 'T2T',
  '00:00:00:02:89:4d' => 'T9T',
  '00:00:00:02:89:28' => 'T10T',
  '00:00:00:02:89:a1' => 'T8T'
}
```

Example:

```
input = 'T4T____T5T____T2T____T10T____T6T____'
(desired) output = '00:00:00:02:89:51, 00:00:00:02:27:bd, 00:00:00:02:89:af, 00:00:00:02:89:28, 00:00:00:02:89:31'
```

My first thought is to loop through each value within the map, see if it exists within input and if so then add the corresponding ID to the output. But this would not be optimal due to unnecessary extra looping. Any suggestions?

Also, my code is using a global variable to use define the map variable. I know this is frowned upon, is there a better way for me to do this? Format of my code below:

```
let dict = new Map()

function customQueryString() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.query(query, (err, res) => {

          res.rows.forEach(psqltag => {
            dict.set(psqltag.m_violator_tag, psqltag.m_translatedid)

        });
    
          resolve(queryStringAddition)  // defined elsewhere doesnt matter for this problem
        })
      })

}

function loopingQueryFunction(loopQuery) {

    client.query(loopQuery, (err, res) => {
        res.rows.forEach(tag => {
           input = tag.violating_tags    // where the input string is found
           output = ???                  // where the translation needs to happen
       }
    }
}

async function asyncCall() {
    let qStringAddition = await customQueryString();
    loopQuery = loopQuery +  qStringAddition
    for (let i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
        console.log("loop " + i)
        await delay(1000)
        
        loopingQueryFunction(loopQuery)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless your string is huge, looping multiple times is perfectly fine.

Comment: @RoboRobok Yes I agree in this case looping is perfectly fine but I just wanted to know what the proper way to do it is.

Comment: An advanced way to do that would be to have a string processor that would analyze char by char and match on the fly. Unnecessary here. Another idea would be to use regex with `/T\d+T/` pattern, as they all seem to be a T followed by number followed by T. Actually, if you want it that way, let me know, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I'm not aware of regex so I'd appreciate to learn how it can be done with that. Is this using the regex-parser npm package?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression to get all translated IDs. Let's assume they are all in `T<number>T` format, which appears true.

```js
const input = 'T4T____T5T____T2T____T10T____T6T____';
const dictEntries = [...dict.entries()].map(([id, translatedId]) => ({id, translatedId}));

const output = input
    .match(/T\d+T/g)
    .map(translatedId => dictEntries.find(entry => entry.translatedId === translatedId))
    .filter(entry => entry !== undefined)
    .map(entry => entry.id);

// ["00:00:00:02:89:51", "00:00:00:02:27:bd", "00:00:00:02:89:af", "00:00:00:02:89:28", "00:00:00:02:89:31"]
```

You can get `output.join(', ')` if you want it as a comma-separated string.